# Obtaining text of spam/offensive posts

Tags: support, spam, offensive

Is there any way for normal people to grab a list of all posts on a site deleted as spam/offensive (presuming I have privileges to view them)?

All routes I've explored are dead ends:

- Archive.org data dump: Does not include deleted posts.
- SEDE: Drops body text from deleted spam/offensive posts.
- API: Does not appear to include deleted posts.
- Scraping results from [a list of IDs](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/643932/deleted-spam-offensive) ([thanks](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/spam-offensive)) by including authorization cookies in the requests: Even with 5 second request intervals (giving a 38 hour ETA on Stack Overflow, for example), logs me out after a few dozen requests (presumably either heavy rate limiting or some sort of automated request protection, or the tokens in the `acct` cookie are periodically invalidated). I had tried with 3 second intervals, then 5, then gave up as I didn't want to press my luck with this one.
- The developers of various spam detection bots were kind enough to share their existing databases with me but we ran into staleness, completeness, and Unicode-related issues.

Is there a polite, acceptable way to do this? I'd like to build a database of spam/offensive posts for some pattern analysis.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can always use [Metasmoke](//metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com), unless that's the "developers of various spam-detection bots" you're referring to.

Comment: @NobodyNada It is, but I'm going to look into the MS API next, to at least see if I can get what they've got in their database (goes back 2 years, not bad), which was just brought up as a suggestion in chat.

Comment: [mSO - Possibly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments).

Comment: No existing way, SE team will have to create and share some new data dump.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299515/deleted-spam-questions-from-stack-exchange-deep-learning) was marked as a duplicate, but has the significant additional requirement that Metasmoke and Charcoal's assorted other dumps are clearly insufficient, so the entire set of deleted spam from Stack Exchange would be a valuable addition for the OP.